# Fastest way to split a string into a multidimensional array of arbitrary dimensions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to determine the fastest way to split a string in JavaScript into a multidimensional array with arbitary dimensions.  Is there a way better than looping over the string and matching brackets of the same depth?

Example string:

```
[1,2,3,[1,2,3,[1,2,3]],4,5,[1,2],[[1,2],[1,2]],[1],[1]]
```

Comment: The input format is a string, it's not a matter of type-checking but of conversion of a string into a multidimensional array.

Comment: The dirtiest way: `var arr = eval('[1,2,3,[1,2,3,[1,2,3]],4,5,[1,2],[[1,2],[1,2]],[1],[1]]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to count for older browsers, you can use JSON.parse:

```
var a = '[1,2,3,[1,2,3,[1,2,3]],4,5,[1,2],[[1,2],[1,2]],[1],[1]]';

var b = JSON.parse(a);
```

For older browsers I can think of one quick and dirty way, some use it as last resort of parsing JSON.

```
var a = '[1,2,3,[1,2,3,[1,2,3]],4,5,[1,2],[[1,2],[1,2]],[1],[1]]';

var b = (new Function('return ' + a + ';'))();
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I'll accept this in 5 minutes when it allows me to do so.